Contradictions in Srimad Bhagavatham and Bhagavad Gita
Namasthe
I have one question
There is a slokam from Srimad Bhagavatham, canto 3 chapter 31
In Srimad Bhagavatham, its mentioned next birth (punarjanma) takes place based on Jiva's Karma under the divine supervision of the Supreme Lord

ŚB 3.31.1
श्रीभगवानुवाच कर्मणा दैवनेत्रेण जन्तुर्देहोपपत्तये । स्त्रिया:
प्रविष्ट उदरं पुंसो रेत:कणाश्रय: ॥ १ ॥
The Personality of Godhead said: Under the supervision of the Supreme
Lord and according to the result of his work, the living entity, the
soul, is made to enter into the womb of a woman through the particle
of male semen to assume a particular type of body.

But Krishna says in BG 9.9 that he is ever detached from all activities and remain neutral

Bhagavad Gita: Chapter 9, Verse 9
न च मां तानि कर्माणि निबध्नन्ति धनञ्जय | उदासीनवदासीनमसक्तं तेषु
कर्मसु || 9||
BG 9.9: O conqueror of wealth, none of these actions bind Me. I remain
like a neutral observer, ever detached from these actions.

In Srimad Bhagavatham 3.31.1 it says the placing of soul in a womb takes place under the divine supervision of the supreme Lord . But In BG 9.9, krishna says I'm not involved in any material activities so does it disprove SB 3.31.1,? Does that mean SB 3.31.1 is false or flawed or non functional due to the contradiction and does not apply?

these verses are not contradictory

Please explain it in detail how it's not contradictory

Lord Krishna is neutral towards all kinds of living entities as said in Bhagavad Gita 9.9. This means that He never hates any soul nor directly interferes in its activities in the material world.
However, being the Supreme controller, Krishna does punish the demonic souls who repeatedly cause pain to other living entities by casting them into the lowest species of life to correct their sinful behavior.
Here's the purport (By Srila Prabhupada) for the Gita verse 9.9 where the neutral stance of Krishna is explained in detail:

One should not think, in this connection, that the Supreme Personality
of Godhead has no engagement. In His spiritual world He is always
engaged. In the Brahma-saṁhitā (5.6) it is stated, ātmārāmasya
tasyāsti prakṛtyā na samāgamaḥ: “He is always involved in His eternal,
blissful, spiritual activities, but He has nothing to do with these
material activities.” Material activities are being carried on by His
different potencies. The Lord is always neutral in the material
activities of the created world. This neutrality is mentioned here
with the word udāsīna-vat. Although He has control over every minute
detail of material activities, He is sitting as if neutral. The
example can be given of a high-court judge sitting on his bench. By
his order so many things are happening – someone is being hanged,
someone is being put into jail, someone is awarded a huge amount of
wealth – but still he is neutral. He has nothing to do with all that
gain and loss. Similarly, the Lord is always neutral, although He has
His hand in every sphere of activity. In the Vedānta-sūtra (2.1.34) it
is stated, vaiṣamya-nairghṛṇye na: He is not situated in the dualities
of this material world. He is transcendental to these dualities. Nor
is He attached to the creation and annihilation of this material
world. The living entities take their different forms in the various
species of life according to their past deeds, and the Lord doesn’t
interfere with them.

Let's also look at the purport for verse 16.20 of the Bhagavad Gita:

It is known that God is all-merciful, but here we find that God is
never merciful to the demoniac. It is clearly stated that the demoniac
people, life after life, are put into the wombs of similar demons,
and, not achieving the mercy of the Supreme Lord, they go down and
down, so that at last they achieve bodies like those of cats, dogs and
hogs. It is clearly stated that such demons have practically no chance
of receiving the mercy of God at any stage of later life. In the Vedas
also it is stated that such persons gradually sink to become dogs and
hogs. It may be then argued in this connection that God should not be
advertised as all-merciful if He is not merciful to such demons. In
answer to this question, in the Vedānta-sūtra we find that the Supreme
Lord has no hatred for anyone. The placing of the asuras, the demons,
in the lowest status of life is simply another feature of His mercy.
Sometimes the asuras are killed by the Supreme Lord, but this killing
is also good for them, for in Vedic literature we find that anyone who
is killed by the Supreme Lord becomes liberated. There are instances
in history of many asuras – Rāvaṇa, Kaṁsa, Hiraṇyakaśipu – to whom the
Lord appeared in various incarnations just to kill them. Therefore
God’s mercy is shown to the asuras if they are fortunate enough to be
killed by Him.

Generally, this act of punishing the evil living entities is performed by Lord Krishna through His energy (Krishna-Shakti) who is commonly known as Maha-maya.

Mahamaya who is known as Durga, Kali, Candi, Bhadrakali, Mohalaksmi,
etc is the embodiment of His external potency as described in the
Candi and it is the thankless task of the Mahamaya to punish the
asuras with Her all powerful weapons in the ten direction of the
material world. She does not only create and maintain this material
world but also she annihilates it according to the direction of the
almighty God.

This Maha-maya potency of Krishna functions in the material world to punish the miscreants as well as to guide the saintly beings towards Krishna for their attainment of liberation or Moksha.
In summary, Lord Krishna's neutrality encompasses all of the below:

Not interfering in the free-will of the conditioned souls
Punishing the evil / miscreants through His energy
Guiding his devotees towards Him


Thanks sir . But actually My question is little different . I have modified the question. Please kindly can you answer it again sir . Actually my question was different I have highlighted my question in bold . Please kindly can you answer for that . Thanks . Apologies if I'm bothering you

Sir my question is different actually. I have updated my question. Can you please look and answer for this sir

The answer will still apply as all activities of the material world including placing a soul into a particular womb is performed by Lord Krishna through His potencies or Shakti.

But Krishna says that he does not involve in any activity in BG 9.9 that's why I wanted to confirm if this sloka from srimad bhagvatham is correct or not?

His energies involve but He remains aloof and His potency is non-different from Him. All verses in the Bhagavatam are correct and in alignment with the Gita. Would suggest first reading the Gita (https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/) followed by hearing the Bhagavatam from devotees of Krishna, to understand the full meaning of the Gita and the Bhagavatam.

Yes sir in Bhagavad Gita Chapter 16 verses 19-20 krishna said I hurl those with demonic character into demonic wombs Both Srila prabhupada and Mukundananda state God(Ishvara) decides our next birth based on karma in their commentaries and they give reference to sloka SB canto 3 chapter 31 verse 1( SB 3.31.1) please check my question I have mentioned , in this sloka it says under the supervision of supreme lord , soul gets new body

So i wanted to check because this both SB 31.3.1 and BG 16.19 are contradictory with BG 9.9 . I read the commentaries sir . So when Krishna says I hurl them into demonic wombs , does it imply krishna himself decides next birth  because in both commentaries it's mentioned Krishna decides our next birth . Pls check these https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/16/verse/19-20 and https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/16/19/

I don't have any further explanation apart from what I've already told.

So when Krishna says I decide next birth ( BG 16.19- I hurl them into demonic wombs , does it mean his energy (Maya ) decides the next birth ?

Please clarify this last query sir . Thanks

Correct. It's like a manager whose assistant completes some small work for him. When the manager tells others, He might say I've done it. A mundane example to help understand...

Namasthe sir. I have one important question Wanted to ask. Can you please kindly answer me sir https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/61678/what-will-happen-if-two-universal-laws-are-conflicting-with-each-other

Is your above question cleared before we discuss the next one? Namaste.
